# can't enter GRUB mode on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: grub2

When I keep pressing esc after turning off my machine, it will show me this

```
GNU GRUB version 2.04
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word,
TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists
possible device or file completions.
```

I have AMD RADEON graphics instead of nvidia. Ubuntu is 20.04. I tried this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7od9dPf4gnM) it doesnt work. Please help, thanks!

Comment: If you type `exit` does it do anything. Did you install in UEFI or BIOS mode and system set to boot in that same boot mode? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair